# How do you subtract two Matrices in spark?

Tags: java, matrix, apache-spark

I am trying to subtract one Matrix  (`org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix`) from another Matrix in Spark. Is there any way to perform Matrix (or Vector) subtraction without writing a function to 'manually' do it?

*Note: both Matrices are the same size*

Comment: Just for clarification - do you ask if subtraction is provided by Spark API?

Comment: @zero323 That, or any API that can operate on a Matrix. I find it hard to believe that this functionality does not exist somewhere.

Comment: [Breeze is pretty cool](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/wiki/Quickstar) and is used internally by Spark. There is also [lazy-linalg](https://github.com/brkyvz/lazy-linalg) but I haven't tried it. Mahout has nice Scala bindings.

Comment: @zero323 To use Breeze for subtraction, would I have to multiply by -1 and then add? I don't see subtraction explicitly listed.

Comment: Yes, as far as I remember.